# Custom MySQL functions Class

Tags: c++, mysql, shared-libraries

I started working on a class including many function regrouping common mysql task that my project (a game server) will need.

Right now there isint much as i am learning how to use mysql with C++

While trying to build this class as a shared library (under linux) i have an error, here it is..

```
error: ‘connect’ was not declared in this scope
```

So.. it is happening in the function `checklogin()` of course I somewhat understand what it means, the problem is that this `connect` is declared in another function `connectdb()` that i made in the same library. I tried to just repeat the pointer thing, but it then lead me to having a seg fault when I enter the `checklogin` function (seg fault actualy come from mysql library, from what the debugger said) so i thought it might not be the right way (or was it?)

Anyway, I was wondering what could be possible solutions to this problem, point to `connect` again? or manage that this pointer get detected by another function
here is the code... (witch by the way, functions code have been pretty much copy/pasted from this tutorial http://www.nitecon.com/tutorials-articles/develop/cpp/c-mysql-beginner-tutorial/)

sssql.cpp

```
    #include "sssql.h"

sssql::sssql()
{
    //ctor
}

sssql::~sssql()
{
    //dtor
}


bool sssql::checklogin(std::string, std::string)
{
    MYSQL *connect;
    MYSQL_RES *res_set;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM account");

    unsigned int i = 0;

    res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);

    unsigned int numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set);

    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) != NULL)
        {
        printf("%s\n",row[i] != NULL ?
        row[i] : "NULL");
        }

}

bool sssql::connectdb()
{
     MYSQL *connect;
    connect=mysql_init(NULL);
    if(!connect)
    {
        printf("MySQL Initialization Failed");
        return 1;
    }

    connect=mysql_real_connect(connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0);

    if(connect){
        printf("Connection Succeeded\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Connection Failed!\n");
    }
}
```

sssql.h

```
#ifndef SSSQL_H
#define SSSQL_H
#include "mysql.h"
#define SERVER "localhost"
#define USER "root"
#define PASSWORD "password"
#define DATABASE "database"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
class sssql
{
    public:
        sssql();
        virtual ~sssql();

        // Check login info
        std::string usrcheck;
        std::string passwd;
        bool connectdb();
        bool checklogin(std::string, std::string);
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // SSSQL_H
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with `connect` is that you create it in `connectdb` function where it's a local variable so once `connectdb` returns `connect` is destroyed.  When you redeclare it in `checklogin()` you essentially creating a separate variable with god only knows what could be stored in it and then you attempt to use it to communicate with MySQL that won't work.

What you should be doing is declaring `connect` as a private class member:

```
class sssql
{
private:
    MySQL *connect;

....
};
```

which will make it in scope for all functions declared in the class.  You can instantiate it during construction or in a separate function like `connectdb()` if you choose.  But before you continue I would strongly recommend reading up on [variable scope](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) and other tutorials from [the same site](http://www.cplusplus.com/).

P.S.  One more suggestion would be to not name the variable `connect` as there are functions n several libraries under the same name.